# Attempting to use OpenCL with Nvidia on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, gpu

I have an Nvidia Quadro 400 GPU. In order to use OpenCL, I installed the following packages:

```
nvidia-340xx
nvidia-340xx-libgl
nvidia-340xx-utils
opencl-nvidia-340xx
ocl-icd
opencl-headers
pyopencl-headers
python-pyopencl
```

When I execute `import pyopencl` in Python, I get the following error:

`ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyopencl/_cffi.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol clCompileProgram, version OPENCL_1.2 not defined in file libOpenCL.so.1 with link time reference`

Am I missing some steps? Is there a more direct way to test whether OpenCL is working or not?